# programming puzzle : how to count number of bacteria that are alive?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, grid

Recently, I had encountered an interesting programming puzzle which had some good twist and turn mentioned in the puzzle. Below the question which amazed me, I simply eager to know if any relevant solution probably in java is feasible for below scenario.

Problem statement:
There is a grid of dimension m*n, initially, a bacterium is present at the bottom left cell(m-1,0) of the grid with all the other cells empty. After every second, each bacteria in the grid divides itself and increases the bacteria count int the adjacent(horizontal,vertical and diagonal) cells by 1 and dies.

**How many bacteria are present at the bottom right cell(m-1,n-1) after n-1 seconds?** 
I had taken references from 
https://www.codechef.com/problems/BGH17
but failed to submit the solution
Below is the image for more insite of problem

[image]

Comment: There's an obvious algorithm that runs in O(m*n*n), and I doubt you can get faster.

Comment: Is it somehow obvious that it has anything to do with knapsack? Doesn't look as if it required NP-anything algorithms...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin honestly I am not aware about NP-anything algorithms so thought it might related to knapsack because of limit and value provided(just a wild guess)

Comment: @BhargavModi its not clear what is the distribution of dividing in the 4 adjacent cells. Each bacteria divides to 2 one horizontaly and one verticaly but if there is space its always to the left and right or pseudorandom with 50% or its not dividing to 2 cells but to 4 instead or what...  Also is there a limit on  bacteria count per cell ?

Comment: @spektre It seems it divides to all adjacent cells (maximum of 8) within the grid.

Comment: @Spektre it says "increases amount in neighbors by one" aka all of them and there is no limit on bacteria count per cell because that isnt mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The starting situation only has a value in the left-most column 0. We need to know the situation in the right-most column n-1 after time n-1. This means that we only have to look at each column once: column x at time x. What happens to column x after time x is no longer important. So we go from left to right, adding up the cells from the previous column:

```
                                                1
                                          1     8
                                    1     7    35
                              1     6    27   104
                        1     5    20    70   230
                  1     4    14    44   133   392
            1     3     9    25    69   189   518
      1     2     5    12    30    76   196   512
1     1     2     4     9    21    51   127   323   ...
```

You will also notice that the result for the last cell is only influenced by two cells in the previous column, and three in the one before that, so to calculate the end result for e.g. the case n=9, you only need to calculate the values in this triangle:

```
                        1
                  1     4    14
            1     3     9    25    69
      1     2     5    12    30    76   196
1     1     2     4     9    21    51   127   323
```

However high the grid is, we only ever have to go up n/2 (rounded up) rows. So the total number of sums we have to calculate is n<sup>2</sup>/4, or n×m if m < n/2.

Also note that we don't have to store all these values at once, because we go column by column from left to right. So we only need a one-dimensional array of size n/2, and the current values in it are transformed like this (e.g. going from column 4 to 5 in the example above):

```
[4, 5, 3, 1]     (0)  ->  0 + 5 - 0 = 5
[9, 5, 3, 1]     (5)  ->  9 + 3 - 5 = 7
[9,12, 3, 1]     (7)  ->  12 + 1 - 7 = 6
[9,12, 9, 1]     (6)  ->  9 + 0 - 6 = 3
[9,12, 9, 4]     (3)  ->  4 + 0 - 3 = 1
[9,12, 9, 4, 1]  (1)  (additional value is always 1)
```

where we iterate over the values from left to right, add up the value to the left and right of the current element, subtract a temporary variable which is initialized to 0, store the result in a temporary variable, and add it to the current element.

---

So the theoretical time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n.m) and the space complexity is O(n) or O(m), whichever is smaller. In real terms, the number of steps is n<sup>2</sup>/4 and the required space is n/2.

---

I don't speak Java, but here's a simple JavaScript code snippet which should easily translate:

```js
function bacteria(m, n) {
    var sum = [1];
    for (var col = 1; col < n; col++) {
        var temp = 0;
        var height = Math.min(col + 1, n - col, m);
        if (height > sum.length) sum.push(0);
        for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            var left = row > 0 ? sum[row - 1] : 0;
            var right = row < sum.length - 1 ? sum[row + 1] : 0;
            temp = left + right - temp;
            sum[row] += temp;
        }
    }
    return sum[0];
}
document.write(bacteria(9, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;    

public class BacteriaProblem {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of Rows: ");
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Columns: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] input = new int[m][n];
        input[m - 1][0] = 1;
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(m - 1 + "~" + 0);
        reproduce(stack, input, n - 1);

        System.out.println("Value at Bottom Right corner after n-1 secs: " + input[m - 1][n - 1]);
      }

      private static void reproduce(Stack<String> stack, int[][] input, int times) {
        //exit condition
        if (times < 1) {
          return;
        }

        //bacteria after splitting
        List<String> children = new ArrayList<>();

        //reproduce all existing bacteria
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
          String[] coordinates = stack.pop().split("~");
          int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);
          int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]);


          for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
              if (i == 0 && j == 0) continue;
              split(input, x + i, y + j, children);
            }
          }
          input[x][y]--;
        }

        //add all children to stack
        for (String coord : children) {
          stack.push(coord);
        }

        //reduce times by 1
        reproduce(stack, input, times - 1);

      }

      private static void split(int[][] input, int x, int y, List<String> children) {
        int m = input.length;
        int n = input[0].length;

        if (x >= 0 && x < m && y >= 0 && y < n) {
          input[x][y]++;
          children.add(x + "~" + y);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was asked this question in an Online Hackerrank test and couldn't solve it at that time.
I did later try to code it and here's the soln in C++,

```
long countBacteriasAtBottomRight(int m, int n){
long grid[m][n];

// Set all to 0, and only bottom left to 1
for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
        grid[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

grid[m-1][0] = 1;

// Start the cycle, do it for (n-1) times
int time = n-1;
vector<long> toBeUpdated;

while (time--){
    cout << "\n\nTime: " << time;

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){

            while (grid[i][j] > 0){
                grid[i][j]--;

                // upper left
                if (i > 0 && j > 0){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i-1);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j-1);
                }

                // upper
                if (i > 0){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i-1);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j);
                }

                // upper right
                if (i > 0 && j < n-1){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i-1);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j+1);
                }

                // left
                if (j > 0){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j-1);
                }

                // bottom left
                if (i < m-1 && j > 0){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i+1);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j-1);
                }

                // bottom
                if (i < m-1){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i+1);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j);
                }

                // bottom right
                if (i < m-1 && j < n-1){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i+1);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j+1);
                }

                // right
                if (j < n-1){
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(i);
                    toBeUpdated.push_back(j+1);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    // Update all other cells
    for (int k=0; k<toBeUpdated.size(); k+=2){          
        grid[toBeUpdated[k]][toBeUpdated[k+1]]++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
        cout << endl;
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
    }

    // Clear the temp vector
    toBeUpdated.clear();
};

return grid[m-1][n-1];
}
```